# Can't Enable Hyper-V on Windows 10 Education laptop

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I am trying to enable Hyper-V on my Windows 10 Education laptop. I have checked the `Hyper-V` option in `Windows feature`, but after rebooting, the option still not enabled (back to unticked). Many articles and threads I have read suggest to turned on `Virtualization`, which I already did, and check if my hardware supports `DEP` and `EPT`. My hardware passes the requirement (i.e. enabled virtualization and supports both `DEP` and `EPT`), but this problem still persists. I need `Hyper-V` to install Android Emulator for Visual Studio.

The image below is taken from `msinfo32` shows that all the `Hyper-V` requirements are met.

[image]

Anyone has solution for this?

Any help would be appreciated. Cheers

Comment: during restart do you get a message that the changes have to be reverted?

Comment: @magicandre1981 no, I did not see that message. Did you ever encounter this problem? What is your workaround?

Comment: do you use 32 or 64bit? Hyper-V needs 64bit Windows

Comment: @magicandre1981 yes I use 64bit

Comment: enable hyper v needs minimum 4GB memory, Please check your  memory size. We could enable it through PowerShell command line "Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All" .

Comment: run msinfo32.exe and export the report and share the nfo file (onedrive share link)

Answer (score 0):

1. Update your BIOS
2. Update your system, making sure that wstorvsp.inf is added to driver store.

Open event log to see if there is any error code and message related.
Open 
Open cbs.log to see what causing it fail to enable the feature.